# What is the growth rate of the products of binomial coefficients?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, real-analysis, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

**Question 1**: Are the following empirically observed relationships true

$$
{n \choose 1^a}{n \choose 2^a}{n \choose 3^a}\cdots {n \choose m^a} 
\sim \exp\bigg(\frac{2n^{1 + \frac{1}{a}}}{a+3}\bigg)
$$
where $a$ is a fixed positive integer and $m = \lfloor n^{1/a}\rfloor$.

$$
{n \choose b}{n \choose 2b}{n \choose 3b}\cdots {n \choose mb} 
\sim \exp\bigg(\frac{n^{2}}{2b}\bigg)
$$
where $b$ is a fixed positive integer and $m = \lfloor n/b\rfloor$.

**Question 2**: What is the growth rate of

$$
{n \choose 1^ab}{n \choose 2^ab}{n \choose 3^ab}\cdots {n \choose m^ab} 
$$

For $a = 3$, the $\%$ error between the asymptotic and the actual product is shown below. We observe that the error is small and is decreasing with $n$?

**Note**: Posted in MO since it was [unanswered in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302368/what-is-the-growth-rate-of-the-products-of-binomial-coefficients).

[image]

Comment: what does Stirling's approximation say here? (I understand there are too many factorials)

Comment: in the second one you probably have $k$ and $m$ confused

Comment: @BrendanMcKay corrected

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer (but the general case should be similar): using Stirling+Euler-MacLaurin+Glaisher's constant we have for $a=1$:
$$\prod_{1\le j\le n}\binom{n}{j}\sim n^{-(n/2+1/3)}e^{n^2/2+n(1-\log(2\pi)/2)+K}$$
with
$$K=1/12-2\zeta'(-1)-\log(2\pi)/2\;.$$
Thus I presume that $A\sim B$ in the OP's question means that
$\log(A)/\log(B)$ tends to 1.